# deployment error in weblogic

Tags: java, jaxb, saml-2.0

while deploying war file in weblogic getting UnsupportedOperationException and ModuleException.

> Caused By: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does
>   not support specification "null" version "null"   at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setSchema(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:561)

I have searched google and changed the version of xerces.jar and xercesImpl.jar to the latest and we are using **opensaml 2.** using java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is something internal, because the developers customize the xerces.jar.
After add the customize package to the new jar, it works.
So, UnsupportedOperationException is mostly related to xerces.jar and xercesImpl.jar

Appreciated your input.
Hitesh